# Factorising into Gaussian primes $4+3i$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-factorization

I want to find the Gaussian prime factors of $(4+3i)$

$$(4+3i)(4-3i) = 25=5^2$$

$$5: (2-i)(2+i)$$
so 
$$(4+3i)(4-3i) = 25=5^2 = (2-i)(2+i)(2-i)(2+i)$$

That was my answer but the solution says:

$$(2-i)(1+2i)$$

Are both correct is the my solution wrong?

Comment: You factorized $\;(4+3i)(4-3i)\;$, yet you were asked *only* about $\;4+3i\;$ !

Comment: So I should choose one of each conjugates?

Comment: I get it now. I should use Euclides algorithm to find the other factor right?

Comment: Yes....just check that you really get what you want. You *already* have the basic decomposition $\;4+3i=(1+2i)(2-i)\;$ . What Euclidean algorithm are you talking about?

Comment: Also think whether you want $(1+2i)(2-i)$ or $-i(1+2i)^2$